# What is Vitali theorem

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

What is the definition of weak and strong convergent sequence in L^p?

I can not seem to find anywhere the proper definition and to see difference between the two.

Also What is Vitalis theorem really about, I don't get it? What does it give to us, and why is it so important?

Recommendation for proper literature is also welcome.

Comment: Well, where have you looked? Virtually any textbook that does any significant work on $L^p$ spaces is going to define strong convergence (and likely weak convergence too), and my brief Google search of "weak convergence lp" gave many promising results.

Comment: For example this one http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic913185.files/Weak-Convergence.pdf it does not define X* and I don't know with what I am working with. Than this one http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT4380/v06/Weakconvergence.pdf does not define strong convergence at all, but it uses it ... and so on. Although last one does provide me with nice explanation of weak convergence.

Comment: That's why you should look at a complete textbook, not just spare notes.

Comment: That is why I wrote that I need recommendation for literature also, if people don't want to be bodered with writhing something so well known for many.

Comment: To which Vitali's Theorem are you referring? There are several.

Comment: Ben, I did not know that. And that makes sense of why I am confused regarding to it. I can not give you answer to that question, as I looked in few text books, trying to make sense of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be a normed linear space ($L^p(A)$ for some measurable set $A$ is a good example, where $1\leq p\leq\infty$). In the following, we will take $X$ to be a real vector space. Then we have:

1. Strong convergence: A sequence $\{f_n\}\subseteq X$ is said to converge strongly in $X$ to $f\in X$ if $||f_n-f||\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.
2. Weak convergence: Define $X^*$ to be the dual of $X$. That is, $X^*:=\{T:X\to\mathbb{R}|T$ is linear and continuous$\}$. Then we say that $\{f_n\}$ converges weakly in $X$ to $f\in X$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty} T(f_n)=T(f)$ for every $T\in X^*$.

If a sequence converges strongly, then it also converges weakly. We also have a partial converse: for $E$ a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $1<p<\infty$, if $\{f_n\}\to f$ weakly in $L^p(E)$, then a subsequence of $\{f_n\}$ converges strongly in $L^p(E)$ if and only if $||f||_p=\lim\inf||f_n||_p$.

A good reference/introduction, in my opinion, and one that seems to be fairly standard is Royden and Fitzpatrick's "Real Analysis".